# Is DeviceInformation.Id persistent in the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, uwp, pairing

For Windows apps, does `DeviceInformation.Id` remain the same between app open/close, system reboots, device disconnect/reconnect, etc.? Can it be used to store "known" devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()` and recorded the Id of several devices. After restarting the computer, their Id did not change.

### Update:

I looked up the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices#save-a-device-for-later-use) for `DeviceInformation` and can tell that the Id is immutable. This is the documentation. Since Id is used as a credential for device information reuse, it is reliable.

Best regards.

Comment: That doesn't prove any more than that on your machine given your set of connected devices the `Id`'s did not change across a reboot. There is no evidence that those `Id`'s will always be stable, e.g. when they get reconnected or reinstalled.

Comment: Hi, I looked up the documentation for `DeviceInformation` and can tell that the Id is immutable. This is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices#save-a-device-for-later-use). Since `Id` is used as a credential for device information reuse, it is reliable.

Comment: So then, replace your answer with that comment.

Comment: Yep, changed. Thank you :)